# Does Uber's api have features for UberDost?

Tags: uber-api

I am working with UberDost, but the application lacks functionalities, for this reason I want to implement my own solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What is UberDost?

Comment: "As an Uber Dost, you earn money by referring drivers to Uber." https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab.android.dost&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, we do not provide UberDost functionality via the API. We will add it to the features request backlog and follow up on this thread if it ever changes.